# Is "He’ll shrieve [meaning absolve] my soul" a correct use of a bracket note?

Tags: citations

I'm working on an essay for my class right now, and I'm not sure if I'm using this bracket note correctly for MLA format.

> “It is the Hermit good!/He singeth loud his godly hymns/That he makes in the wood./He’ll shrieve [meaning absolve] my soul, he’ll wash away/ The Albatross’s blood.” (Coleridge, lines 509-513; page 461).

Here is the quote without my addition:

> “It is the Hermit good!/He singeth loud his godly hymns/That he makes in the wood./He’ll shrieve my soul, he’ll wash away/ The Albatross’s blood.” (Coleridge, lines 509-513; page 461).

**Am I using the bracket note appropriately?** If not is there an appropriate way to integrate this note within the quotation without breaking it? In guides online, I've only seen brackets in quotes used to replace the word in question.

Comment: This question would be more appropriate at [academia.stackexchange.com](https://academia.stackexchange.com) where there are already hundreds of questions about MLA format.

Answer (score 9):

Here is what the MLA's style guide has to say about using brackets within quotations:

> In rare cases, you might need to supply information in a quotation. This is done with brackets, as the following example shows:
>
> > “My father had often hinted that she [Miss Betsey] seldom conducted herself like an ordinary Christian” (Dickens).
>
> While the bracketed portion in this example is acceptable, it’s also a bit awkward. It’s generally best to supply this kind of information in your own prose. You might revise as follows:
>
> > David Copperfield introduces Miss Betsey with his father’s description of her: “My father had often hinted that she seldom conducted herself like an ordinary Christian” (Dickens).
>
> <sub>Wallace, Joseph. "How to Avoid Bracketed Changes in Quotations." *MLA.org*, 26 May 2021, [style.mla.org/avoid-bracketed-changes/](https://style.mla.org/avoid-bracketed-changes/). Accessed 22 March 2024</sub> .

Since the cited page's URL includes *avoid-bracketed-changes*, one can gather that using brackets is discouraged.

In your case, note that when you're quoting multiple lines of poetry (anything more than three lines), you should use a blockquote instead of separating lines with dashes. You have several options to avoid the brackets. You can use a sidenote:

> It is the Hermit good!
> He singeth loud his godly hymns
> That he makes in the wood.
> He’ll shrieveº my soul, he’ll wash away
>      
>      
>      
>       º*absolve*
> The Albatross’s blood.

Alternatively, you can use a footnote:

> It is the Hermit good!
> He singeth loud his godly hymns
> That he makes in the wood.
> He’ll shrieve† my soul, he’ll wash away
> The Albatross’s blood.
>
> <sub>†*shrieve*: absolve</sub>

You can also explain the word in parentheses as part of your own text surrounding the quotation. For example:

> Seeing the third figure in the boat, the mariner is gladdened:
>
> > It is the Hermit good!
> > He singeth loud his godly hymns
> > That he makes in the wood.
> > He’ll shrieve my soul, he’ll wash away
> > The Albatross’s blood.
>
> (*Shrieve* means *absolve*.)

As a last resort, you can use brackets if that seems most preferable to you. But in that case you do not need *meaning*:

> It is the Hermit good!
> He singeth loud his godly hymns
> That he makes in the wood.
> He’ll shrieve [absolve] my soul, he’ll wash away
> The Albatross’s blood.

Finally, ask yourself whether you actually need to explain the meaning of *shrive* at all. Who is your audience? If your remit is to tell your classmates the poem's story through paraphrase and selective quotation, you might indeed need to gloss less common words (such as *shrive*). But if your task is to analyze, rather than merely summarize, the poem, you can assume your audience knows what *shrive* means.

Comment: I have no idea whether this question is on-topic. Since we have a [tag:citations] tag, I'm guessing it's on-topic, but even if it's closed as off-topic, you'll still have this answer for your delectation.